# Spark error : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/sources/v2/StreamWriteSupport

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-sandbox

I am using Spark in Horton works, when i execute the below code i am getting exception. i also have a separate spark instance running in my system - same code is working fine in it.

I need to do anything different in Horton works to resolve the below error?.kindly assist me.

```
[root@sandbox-hdp bin]# ./spark-shell
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
18/08/31 11:36:44 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
Spark context Web UI available at http://172.17.0.2:4041
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1535715404685).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
          ____              __
         / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
        _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
       /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.2.0.2.6.3.0-235
          /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_151)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

    scala> :paste
    // Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

    import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    val df = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .load("hdfs://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8020/city.csv")
    df.show()
    df.printSchema()

    // Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/sources/v2/StreamWriteSupport
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
  at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:370)
  at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
  at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
  at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:43)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
  at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filterImpl(TraversableLike.scala:247)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filter(TraversableLike.scala:259)
  at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:104)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:533)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:89)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass(DataSource.scala:89)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:304)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:156)
  ... 53 elided

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.v2.StreamWriteSupport
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  ... 86 more
```

All the CSV drivers are properly copied to jar folder inside spark. This is the  same exception i am facing to connect to Excel, Hbase and apache phoenix.

I am facing this only in horton works.

Comment: Telling from the documentation, this class seems to have been added in Spark 2.3.1, and your shell is showing 2.2.1. https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/sources/v2/StreamWriteSupport.html

Comment: after adding Latest Spark code Jar it worked  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding Latest Spark code Jar it worked

Comment: spark code jar? what does that even mean?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question.I found a mistake in my pom.xml that my spark version is diffrent with my environment. So, I changed the spark version and kept the same environment and solved this error.